# A cursor in a function - MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I have a task to use cursor to write a function that receives a movie title and then returns pay of actors involved in this movie.

I wrote something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getPay(movieTitle varchar(90))
RETURNS int;
BEGIN
DECLARE P int;
DECLARE done int DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE payCursor CURSOR FOR 
(SELECT A.pay FROM actors A JOIN movie M ON M.id=A.movie WHERE M.title=movieTitle);
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;
OPEN payCursor;
loop_read : LOOP
    FETCH payCursor INTO P;
    IF done THEN 
        LEAVE loop_read;
    END IF;
    RETURN P;
END LOOP;
CLOSE payCursor;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

It's not a secret it's not working. I don't know how to return a set, moreover as I've read it's not possible in MariaDB. I tried to create temporary table but it's not good solution if you want to use this function several times. Also I would like to use this function in another task where I have to write a procedure to pay all the actors. I'm not sure I got the idea of cursors.

Answer (score 0):

That function seems to be getting *one* (any one) row from the query.  This would replace the function:

```
SELECT  A.pay
    FROM  actors A
    JOIN  movie M  ON M.id=A.movie
    WHERE  M.title=movieTitle)
    LIMIT 1;
```

Or, since it is a function, get rid of the cursor, and have only that in the function.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. I want to obtain all actor's pay. I wouldn't use cursors, function if  I didn't have to but that's the task.

Comment: @Awerde - What do you mean "that's the task"?  Is this a homework assignment?  Usually, the 'task' is to make an app work and work well; use a function if it helps; don't use a function if it gets in the way.

Comment: It's kinda my homework, yeah. I asked my teacher about it today, there's some kind of mistake in it. I asked here because I didn't know if I'm not understanding something well or it's just silly task which it is as you noticed. I would't use cursors or function over trivial query. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Awerde - OK.  In the list of SQL things to learn, cursors is quite far down my list.  They are inefficient, clumsy, and distract from the key lesson of how SQL works on "sets" of rows, avoiding the one-row-at-a-time mentality of most programming languages.